# drop rows based on dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, drop

Hello Python Experts,
I import data into a python dataframe from a csv file which goes through April 2021. But then I want to drop any data after 2019. Playing around with the data.drop() feature, but cant' seem to figure out the syntax. How do i drop all data after 2019 in the dataframe?

Please see my code and csv file (form which the dataframe is being created) and advice. Thanks!
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
index_data =pd.read_csv('CSUSHPISA.csv')
index_data['DATE'] =pd.to_datetime(index_data['DATE'])
index_data.set_index('DATE', inplace=True)

print(index_data)
```

Current result:
[image]

data.drop()????

Comment: please post a dummy data

Comment: You want to filter to _keep_ dates before 2019. `df = df[df.index.year <= 2019]`

Comment: @UBS Please let me know if the following answer helped

Comment: Apologies, tried to attach the csv file but not able to do so in Stack overflow. But michlimes' response has answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

Try `loc`:

```
index_data.loc[:"2019"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it as follows:

```
index_data.drop(index_data[index_data['DATE'].dt.year > 2019].index, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.loc` method which is used to filter Pandas dataframes ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)), e.g.:

```py
import pandas as pd
index_data = pd.read_csv(r'https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/fredgraph.csv?bgcolor=%23e1e9f0&chart_type=line&drp=0&fo=open%20sans&graph_bgcolor=%23ffffff&height=450&mode=fred&recession_bars=on&txtcolor=%23444444&ts=12&tts=12&width=1168&nt=0&thu=0&trc=0&show_legend=yes&show_axis_titles=yes&show_tooltip=yes&id=CSUSHPISA&scale=left&cosd=1987-01-01&coed=2021-04-01&line_color=%234572a7&link_values=false&line_style=solid&mark_type=none&mw=3&lw=2&ost=-99999&oet=99999&mma=0&fml=a&fq=Monthly&fam=avg&fgst=lin&fgsnd=2020-02-01&line_index=1&transformation=lin&vintage_date=2021-07-12&revision_date=2021-07-12&nd=1987-01-01')
index_data['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(index_data['DATE'])
index_data.set_index('DATE', inplace=True)

print(index_data.loc[index_data.index.year <= 2019])
```

Results:

```
            CSUSHPISA
DATE                 
1987-01-01     63.967
1987-02-01     64.426
1987-03-01     64.736
1987-04-01     65.135
1987-05-01     65.569
...               ...
2019-08-01    210.422
2019-09-01    211.062
2019-10-01    211.649
2019-11-01    212.438
2019-12-01    213.365

[396 rows x 1 columns]
```